# hibernate search not indexing from remote windows server database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I have increased the number of connections in the sql server remote db I am connecting to, to 3000. When I deploy a war from another remote windows server, the below hibernate search query does not return any matching names after login but when I deploy thesame war on the windows server having the database, the hibernate search returns matching results having login in the dashboard. Here is snippets

```
@Transactional
    public List<Books> finding(String searchTerm) { 

        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1).onFields("name")
                .matching(searchTerm).createQuery();

        javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Books.class);

        List<Books> bList = null;
        try {
            jpaQuery.setMaxResults(50);
            bList = jpaQuery.getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            // do nothing

        }

        return bList;
    }
```

is there anything I am missing to enable me get results of hibernate search from a remote server

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you're using the Lucene integration (the default) and not the Elasticsearch one.

Lucene indexes are stored on the filesystem, so your two servers, with two different filesystem, are simply using two different copies of the indexes: one contains the indexed documents because you triggered indexing on that server, the other is empty because you did not.

If your two servers are supposed to run independently, with two different databases (like a production server and a development server), then you simply need to trigger reindexing on both servers.

On the other hand, if your two servers are supposed to connect, read and write to the same database, you are effectively running a distributed application.
You need to take specific (and non-trivial) steps to be able to synchronize an index between distributed servers.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54761525/6692043) and [this section of the reference documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-architecture).

Comment: on a distributed system like mine, will elastic search solve the problem

Comment: Mostly, yes. As mentioned in my answer it has rough edges, but it's much simpler than setting up a JMS or JGroups cluster.